Electron adds @xenova/transformers, causing an error in parsing the scss file containing @tailwind utilities;
After I added @xenova/transformers, I got the following error while running build.
[1] Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[1] expected "{".
[1]      ╷
[1] 1197 │   -: |\s;
[1]      │         ^
[1]      ╵
[1]   src/renderer/App.scss 1197:9  root stylesheet

Remove @xenova/transformers from dependencies or @tailwind utilities from scss file; error disappears.
